# How to add overlay text to camera screen in xamarin forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I would like to add an overlay to the camera.How can it be done in **xamarin forms**

Comment: What control are you using to display the camera in the first place?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate answer is always that you can write a custom renderer for your camera control and add the overlay using you platform native capabilities.

For a Xamarin.Forms solution that doesn't involve custom renderers it is important to know what camera control you are using to begin with.

If you are using the [XLabs camera control](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera) you could inject your custom `MediaPicker.cs` directly after registering the service.

Answer (score 0):

A customrenderer is the answer. You could easily use AVFoundation, see this blog post that got me going https://blog.xamarin.com/how-to-display-camera-ios-avfoundation/.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by creating a custom control following the steps in this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view

It's very basic and you'll need to add more things to have a full usable camera, but it's a good start.

There is a discussion around the focus for that camera in here: [Camera Using custom Camera Preview Renderer is not clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136669/camera-using-custom-camera-preview-renderer-is-not-clear/49681149#49681149)