# Camera Using custom Camera Preview Renderer is not clear

Tags: xamarin.android, android-camera

I am using the following link to display the camera preview using Custom renderers
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/

I was able to bring up the camera preview. But the preview is not at all clear. There is no Auto focus as well.
 Screenshot for reference
[image]

How can I make the camera preview clearer, because I wish to use the same later on for OCR.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already figured this out but I'm going to post the solution here for reference.

You need to setup the "Focus Mode" in the Camera properties.

```
Camera Preview = Camera.Open(1);
// Set the parameters.
if (Preview != null)
{
    Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = Preview.GetParameters();
    // Autofocus
    cameraParameters.FocusMode = Camera.Parameters.FocusModeContinuousPicture;
    // Set
    cameraPreview.Preview.SetParameters(cameraParameters);
}
```

For the example you mentioned (the one in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view/) you should place this code in you Android Cutom Renderer (CameraPreviewRenderer method OnElementChanged).

It worked for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using the code from the same example for View Custom Renderer. But I cannot find `Camera Preview = Camera.Open(1);` this line anywhere inside `OnElementChanged)`

Answer (score -1):

```
//Write logic inside the RunOnUiThread.

MainActivity.Instance.RunOnUiThread(() => { SetupUserInterface(); SetupEventHandlers(); AddView(view); cameraQuality = CameraQuality.High; });
```