# Image from Camera Preview using Customer Renderer is not clear

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, custom-renderer

I've followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/view) article and implemented a Customer Renderer that's used to display a preview video stream from the device's camera.

I intend to capture a frame from the live stream and feed it into Tesseract OCR in order to read a number printed on a ticket.

> **My problem is that the image from camera preview is almost always not focused**. So it is useless for its intended purpose.

An [identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44136669/camera-using-custom-camera-preview-renderer-is-not-clear) has been asked years ago here in SO, but the accepted answer is not at all helpful for me.

This is the code of `OnElementChanged` event of `CameraPreviewRenderer`:

```
void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<CameraPreview> e)
{
    CameraFragment newFragment = null;

    if (e.OldElement != null)
    {
        e.OldElement.PropertyChanged -= OnElementPropertyChanged;
        cameraFragment.Dispose();
    }
    if (e.NewElement != null)
    {
        this.EnsureId();

        e.NewElement.PropertyChanged += OnElementPropertyChanged;

        ElevationHelper.SetElevation(this, e.NewElement);
        newFragment = new CameraFragment { Element = element };                
    }

    FragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
        .Replace(Id, cameraFragment = newFragment, "camera")
        .Commit();
    ElementChanged?.Invoke(this, new VisualElementChangedEventArgs(e.OldElement, e.NewElement));
}
```

This is a piece from `class CameraFragment`. Method `RetrieveCameraDevice` is the one that opens the camera (I think).

```
class CameraFragment : Fragment, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener
{
    CameraDevice device;
    CaptureRequest.Builder sessionBuilder;
    CameraCaptureSession session;
    CameraTemplate cameraTemplate;
    CameraManager manager;

    .... 


    public async Task RetrieveCameraDevice(bool force = false)
    {
        if (Context == null || (!force && initTaskSource != null))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (device != null)
        {
            CloseDevice();
        }

        await RequestCameraPermissions();
        if (!cameraPermissionsGranted)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!captureSessionOpenCloseLock.TryAcquire(2500, TimeUnit.Milliseconds))
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Timeout waiting to lock camera opening.");
        }

        IsBusy = true;
        cameraId = GetCameraId();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cameraId))
        {
            IsBusy = false;
            captureSessionOpenCloseLock.Release();
            Console.WriteLine("No camera found");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics = Manager.GetCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                StreamConfigurationMap map = (StreamConfigurationMap)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.ScalerStreamConfigurationMap);

                previewSize = ChooseOptimalSize(map.GetOutputSizes(Class.FromType(typeof(SurfaceTexture))),
                    texture.Width, texture.Height, GetMaxSize(map.GetOutputSizes((int)ImageFormatType.Jpeg)));
                sensorOrientation = (int)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.SensorOrientation);
                cameraType = (LensFacing)(int)characteristics.Get(CameraCharacteristics.LensFacing);

                if (Resources.Configuration.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
                {
                    texture.SetAspectRatio(previewSize.Width, previewSize.Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    texture.SetAspectRatio(previewSize.Height, previewSize.Width);
                }

                initTaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<CameraDevice>();
                Manager.OpenCamera(cameraId, new CameraStateListener
                {
                    OnOpenedAction = device => initTaskSource?.TrySetResult(device),
                    OnDisconnectedAction = device =>
                    {
                        initTaskSource?.TrySetResult(null);
                        CloseDevice(device);
                    },
                    OnErrorAction = (device, error) =>
                    {
                        initTaskSource?.TrySetResult(device);
                        Console.WriteLine($"Camera device error: {error}");
                        CloseDevice(device);
                    },
                    OnClosedAction = device =>
                    {
                        initTaskSource?.TrySetResult(null);
                        CloseDevice(device);
                    }
                }, backgroundHandler);

                captureSessionOpenCloseLock.Release();
                device = await initTaskSource.Task;
                initTaskSource = null;
                if (device != null)
                {
                    await PrepareSession();
                }
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to open camera.", ex);
                Available = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm supposed to setup the "Focus Mode" in the Camera properties somewhere in this code. But I can't figure out a way to do this.

Comment: Do you call AutoFocus on the camera at least once?

Comment: @Cheesebaron No, because I don't know where or how I can do this

Comment: What is CameraFragment? It is probably in there.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Can you please check the edit I made?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos You could check the link below about how to set the `Camera state`. https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/android5.0/Camera2Basic/Camera2Basic/Camera2BasicFragment.cs